# Lockers at train station Hardbrücke in Zürich?

Tags: trains, switzerland, zurich

I'm going to Zürich, Hardbrücke tomorrow evening. I have a big suitcase with me which I don't want to carry all along. So I want to place it in a locker. In the Internet I can't find any information if there are lockers available. Is there any reliable information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since no one answered today, I just checked it out. Actually, there are no lockers at Zürich, Hardbrücke station. But the main station is very close, only one station away. You can get there a locker for 24 hours for 5 franks. There are small lockers available for notebook cases or similar stuff and big lockers for suitcases.

Another station close to Zürich, Hardbrücke that has lockers is Zürich Oerlikon. But the choice is not that big as at the main station. The prices are similar.